# Saving and displaying uploaded image

Tags: javascript, html, image, input

I have an already existing picture and I want to upload a new one and replace the old picture, but this code is not working. (I have a button whose onclick attribute is photoSave().) Can someone tell what's wrong with this Javascript code and maybe write a possible solution?

This is the important part of the code:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="profilePic" id="profilePic">
          <img src="prof.jpg" id="pictureToShow" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="photoButton">
          <label class="btn btn-default btn-file" style="width:220px" onclick="photoChange()">
            Profilkép megváltoztatása <input type="file" accept="image/*" style="display: none" id="newPhoto">
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function photoChange() {
        document.getElementById("photoButton").innerHTML = '<button type="button" style="width:110px" class="btn btn-success btn-s" onclick="photoSave()">Mentés</button><button type="button" style="width:110px" class="btn btn-danger btn-s" onclick="photoSave()">Mégse</button>'
      }

      function photoSave() {
        document.getElementById("photoButton").innerHTML = '<label class="btn btn-default btn-file" style="width:220px" onclick="photoChange()">Profilkép megváltoztatása<input type="file" accept="image/*" style="display: none"></label>'

        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
          var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#pictureToShow').attr('src', e.target.result);
          }

          reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: A file input has no `src`, you have to use FileReader in order to view an selected image: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005678/how-to-upload-an-image-with-jquery-client-side-and-add-it-to-a-div

Comment: The onclick attribute of your button is photoChange() not photoSave().

Comment: You can try this method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094012/how-to-upload-preview-image-before-upload-through-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/refresh-image-with-a-new-one-at-the-same-url

Comment: @Max I know, I have two buttons.

Answer (score 0):

When you're uploading a file via `input type="file"`, the file is not yet saved in your server.

Two solutions:

1. So you need to put this file in your resources repo on your web
   server.
2. Or you can preview the image, see
   [Preview an image before it is uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

Add the following js in your function:

```
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#pictureToShow').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
```

Moreover, your image does not have an ID attribute, so you need to change `<img src="prof.jpg" />` for `<img src="prof.jpg" id="pictureToShow" />`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner, I don't really understand what you mean. Can you add an example code please? But I don't have a web server yet, the code is just on my computer.

Comment: See the link that I passed above. I'm adding the exemple in my response.

Comment: Let us know when your code is working (and accept the response if it okay for you).

Comment: I use Bootstrap, maybe that's why you don't understand.

Comment: Does not working with modification of input & selector ?

Comment: Have you try this ?
Put `<input type="file" accept="image/*" style="display: none" id="newPhoto">` out of `div photoButton`.
As you're not fetching jquery (I think), change the `$('#pictureToShow').attr('src', e.target.result);` to `document.getElementById('pictureToShow').setAttribut‌​e('src', e.target.result);`